# Artificial Neural Network fails to recognize the image made by Paint

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mnist

I trained my ANN with MNIST dataset(with 50000 training inputs) and ran. I get an accuracy rate of 91-92%(which is high) when i try the test inputs included in the MNIST dataset.But if I give my Paint image as an input to my trained ANN, it fails to recognize the digits. Even the most clear ones. However, if i download the image of a digit from internet, it recognizes with a high accuracy rate. So, I don't get why my ANN dos recognize everything but the images made by Paint.
(MNIST dataset contains images which have white-coloured digits on a black background.)

Comment: which programming language is being used and how are the images being read in to the program?

Comment: Matlab. I read the .png file by "imread" function and vectorize the obtained matrix like the ones in my training dataset. Training inputs are representing an image of 28*28 pixel square and i try the same size. @pm101

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, I found the solution. It was actually not about the file formats. The problem was the inconsistency between the dataset(handwritten digits) and the test images that i produced by Paint. They were too neat for a human to write by hand. So it was failing. However, after i produced normal(handwritten not typed) images, it started recognizing with high ratios.

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the image from Paint matches that of the images used to train your network.

If the formats are different, the characteristics of a digit in the Paint image (bitmap?) may not match those the network is trained to recognise (compressed?) in the training data/downloaded images.

Comment: Both of them are .png files if you are asking about that. Or maybe i couldn't get what you exactly meant. If they are both PNG images, is there anything further to analyze? @mids

Answer (score 0):

Did an experiment with paint and downloading a PNG online, two differences: Bit depth and colour depth.

```
imread of a PNG with paint automatically creates a uint8 [28x28x3] matrix

imread of a downloaded PNG creates a uint16[28x28] matrix
```

double check this with your working PNGs

try converting the paint to the same format in MATLAB, for me, for example this is:

```
png_paint_16 = uint16(rgb2gray(imread('PANTPNG.png')))*257
```

Comment: Actually, when i tried with downloaded images, i saw that they were also 3 dimensional and having a depth. For this reason, i moved the the pixel values to a vector and got rid of the 3rd dimension. If one of the matrices(either paint or downloaded) had less then 3 dimensions, i would have got an error. Because i am doing this "3rd dimension removal" for any image i read. And i tried your code for conversion but unfortunately it is still failing. @pm101